# External LoadBalancer in Azure VM

Tags: azure

Azure powershell command Get-AzureDeployment -ServiceName "myservicename" returns the details of deployment in production slot. The returned value has variable LoadBalancers, now in my understanding we cannot create external loadbalancers explicitly in Azure, external loadbalancing is achieved using loadbalanced set or traffic manager in case of disparate deployments.

I was wondering what is returned in variable LoadBalancers and what is the purpose

Comment: @Shaun: Are you saying that you want to know the purpose of the LoadBalancers field? Sorry, I thought you were asking the purpose of internal load balancing.                                                                        Yes, that's correct, I am not why Azure has LoadBalancers field when there is not concept of creating External Load Balancers.

Answer (score 0):

**What is it?** It is internal load balancing.

**What is its purpose?** You can do load balancing behind a private IP address. This enables high availability plus additional security, because the private IP is only available via the Cloud service. Everything below the internal IP is more private yet still highly available to the presentation tier.

```
                  external IP
                       |
                       |
                presentation tier (front end)
                       |
                       |
                  internal IP  
                       |
                       |
              internal load balancing
                |                |
                |                |
           business tier      data tier
           servers            servers
```

See http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/internal-load-balancing/

Comment: Thanks Shaun, I am not sure for the purpose of "LoadBalancers" Field, I can see the name of ILB in "InternalLoadBalancerName".

Comment: Are you saying that you want to know the purpose of the `LoadBalancers` field? Sorry, I thought you were asking the purpose of internal load balancing.